# What is the meaning of ...不断向产业链的高端提升是发展趋势的要求?

Tags: meaning

I can't quite get the last part of this

> 专家：这个问题不能一刀切。对于东部的企业，因为起步较早，有一定产业规模和资金积累，所以调整产业结构，提高技术含量，不断向产业链的高端提升是发展趋势的要求。

Can I rewrite the last bit thus:

> 不断向产业链的高端提升是发展趋势的要求。= 发展趋势的要求是不断向产业链的高端的提升。
>
> 发展趋势的要求是不断向产业链的高端的提升。

develop trend 的 demand is non-stop to supply chain 的 high-end 的 increase

= the development trend is towards an ever increasing luxury car market.

Comment: Hmmm...the last sentence "the development trend is towards an ever increasing luxury car market." sure is ok, but you can't just swap 不断向产业链的高端提升是发展趋势的要求。to 发展趋势的要求是不断向产业链的高端的提升。it's like saying "Having four wheels is a requirement of making a car" to "Making a car is the requirement of having four wheels?". But somehow in the end, you translated it to a correct English sentence? Don't know how you did it, but to me swapping the Chinese bit doesn't make sense.

Comment: Having a second look, 发展趋势的要求是不断向产业链的高端提升。Removing the的makes a lot more sense, I was wondering what was wrong with it

Comment: I thought '高端' was an adjective for '提升' = 'increase'. Is that not so?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused because you're equating 高端 with the English word "high end."

I think a much better translation would be "one of the best."

And your sentence will become:

> 不断向产业链的*高端* **提升**是发展趋势的要求。

Translating this you could say:

> always working **towards** becoming *(one of) the best* suppliers is necessary for development.

Comment: What do you think 产业链 is then? You can't really just leave it out, can you?

Comment: That is in my translation as "supply chain".

Comment: 专家：我们企业应该提高产品技术附加值。
主持人：现在提高技术附加值是否是中国汽车零部件企业的唯一出路？
Talking to a Chinese friend, she agrees with you. She explains it like this: there are many 汽车零部件企业， they are all vying to be 'the best' (高端）or 'top players in their industry'. She said '产业链‘ here is 'car component suppliers' and not 'supply chain' and '提升‘ is 'improvement'. The requirements for improvement '提升的要求‘ are 3, 1调整产业结构, 2提高技术含量, 3不断向产业链的高端提升. Would you agree？

Comment: I assume the first 2 sentences are further context right?

If so, I think it makes a lot more sense because originally, it sounded like the speaker wanted to get a better supply chain. However, it makes more sense for the speaker to say that they want to become of the best suppliers. I've modified my answer accordingly.

Also, yes, 3 things necessary are as you say.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that was a bit difficult for me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

should be 发展趋势的要求是不断向产业链的高端提升 rather than 发展趋势的要求是不断向产业链的高端<del>的</del>提升
here 高端 is not adj, it's noun. Like@biubiubiu mentioned, it means "Upper level(of chain)"

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to separate this sentence into phrases:

```
不断 向 产业链的高端 提升 是 发展趋势 的 要求
```

The main point of the sentence is

```
提升 是 要求
```

All words before "提升" should be adjective here.

Comment: I think this is the right way to dissect the sentence and extract the basic elements of it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let's analyze the easy stuff first. You have a 是 there, that you can use to split the sentence in two parts:

不断向产业链的高端提升 and 发展趋势的要求

The second one is pretty straight-forward, you have a noun phrase 发展趋势 that translates to "development trend", but even better here I think is "further development", as 趋势 carries redundant semantics in English. What it conveys here is going upward from a lower point, which is inherent in "development"; the whole thing modifies (的) the noun 要求 "requirement", "necessity", but also "precondition", therefore:

> the precondition for further development

Now the hard part: here you have an adverb 不断 "continually" that (hold fast!) binds with 向 "toward". As you know, in Chinese there's a loose distinction between what in western languages we call verb and particle, so you have:

> continually moving toward

Then there it goes 产业链, "industry chain" or "industrial chain" as you read [here](http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=hwcfyHLc9ZxYKf7tv81DvxOvbPLO_h5XiGDgisMCxN66N5c-dBkCDsjerp5VPAREpfJhb-Yu3Yc_bovY1AzG0a). It is not necessarily the same as "supply chain", but here english native speakers might have a different opinion. It modifies (的) the following 高端提升. This is a noun phrase as well. I agree with other posters who read 高端 as "high level" as in "high level increase", which you can simply interpret as "improvement".

Finally we put it all together:

> The continual improvement of the industrial chain is precondition for further development.

Answer (score 1):

产业链is the whole chain of one industry, it's not a supply chain. supply chain is 供应链。供应链是产业链的一部分，而且是上游的一部分。一般研发、生产、供应链等是产业链的上游，而销售和售后等是产业链的下游。不断向产业链的高端提升是发展趋势的要求, it means the government requires all the car making companies develop and improve their technologies, aesthetic level, management skills, and marketing skills. 发展趋势acturally indicate a trend and a goal,向高端提升就是这个趋势的要求，但是这个趋势是什么？文章没有具体说，你可以理解这个趋势就是从低端制造业走向高端制造业。向高端提升 is an endocentric phrase, the main verb is 提升，improvement,“向高端” 是 “提升”的要求和方向，the carmaker should improve their products and their producing abilities towards a higher level,perhaps to gain more intellectual properties,or gain more rights on making the standard and so on.so you can't add 的 between 向高端 and 提升。

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused about 产业链的高端, is that right?

It may be translated as `high level of supply chain`.

I think he want to express that the companies should become the creator, not just the manufacturer.

Comment: You are right: I am confused! Seems entirely weird to talk about 'the high end of the supply chain', 'not the high end of the market'. Can't see '高端' as 'downstream', where are you getting that from?

Comment: @Pedroski Oh, maybe I gave you a wrong answer, just fixed it. And also sorry for that I can't give you any ref, coz I just deduced it  according to context. You can see '高端' as 'high level' in this sentence. So  he want to say 'become high level of supply chain', which means 'becoming the creator'.

Answer (score 0):

不断向产业链的高端提升是发展趋势的要求

`Keeping upgrade the chain towards the high-end market is the development trend.`